# Solving a discrete equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences, characteristics

Consider the following equation:

$$-\epsilon u''(x) + \beta u'(x) = 1, \qquad x \in (0, 1) \qquad u(0) = 0, \quad u(1) = 1$$

where $\beta > 0$ and $0 < \epsilon \ll \beta$. I constructed a finite difference scheme and obtained

$$-\frac{2\epsilon + \beta h}{2h^2} u_{i-1} + \frac{2\epsilon}{h^2} u_i - \frac{2\epsilon - \beta h}{2h^2} u_{i+1} = 1$$
or, equivalently,
$$-\frac{h^2}{\epsilon} - (1+Pe)u_{i-1} + 2u_i - (1-Pe) u_{i+1} = 0, \; i = 1, ..., N-1$$
$$u_0 = 0, \; u_N = 1$$
where $u_i = u(x_i), \; x_i = ih,\; h = \frac{1}{N}, \; Pe = \frac{\beta h}{2 \epsilon}.$

How can I solve this discrete equation? Associating the characteristic equation? I didn't understand this method.
Can someone explain me?

Comment: What finite difference schemes did you use? It looks like you used central difference with second order accuracy for both the first and second derivatives, in which case your discretised ODE should become

$$u_{k+1} = \frac{1}{\beta h - 2 \epsilon} \left[ -4 \epsilon u_{k} + (\beta h + 2 \epsilon) u_{k-1} + 2 h^{2} \right] $$

Now, you require a _two_ initial conditions, $u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$, to start iterating.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used central difference. $$ u_i \approx \frac{u_{i+1} - u_{i-1}}{2h}, \; \; u''_i  \approx \frac{u_{i+1} - 2u_i + u_{i-1}}{h^2}.$$

Comment: So now you need to get your $u_{1}$. Can you see how you might do that?

Comment: From your equation. We know $u_N$ and $u_0$.

Comment: You can get $u_{1}$ from $u_{0}$ by applying the backward or forward Euler method for one step.

Comment: I don't know this method. I tried to read about it, but i didn't understand.

Comment: It is a boundary value problem, not an initial value problem.

Comment: Where is the PDE?

Answer (score 1):

You have a linear system of $N-1$ equations in the $N-1$ variables $u_1,\dots u_{n-1}$. I do not consider $u_0$ and $u_N$ as variables, since you know their values. It's a system of a special form, a [tridiagonal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm), for which there is an algorithm to find the solution. The first equation is
$$
2\,u_1-(1-P\,e)u_2=\frac{h^2}{\epsilon},
$$
and the last one
$$
-(1+P\,e)u_{N-2}+2\,u_{N-1}=(1-P\,e)+\frac{h^2}{\epsilon}.
$$
The solution can be found also with the technique of Diference equations. A solution of the homogeneous equation will be of the form $A\,r^i$ for some $r$. Pluging this in the equation we find
$$
r=1,\quad r=\frac{1+P\,e}{1-P\,e}.
$$
Since constants are solutions of the homegeneous equation, a particular solution can be found of the form $C\,i$. The general solution will be
$$
u_i=A+B\Bigl(\frac{1+P\,e}{1-P\,e}\Bigr)^i+C\,i.
$$

Comment: It is true, but for $u_i$ I have to get a formula independent of other $u_j$. (With Thomas algoritm, $u_i$ is obtained according to $u_{i+1}$). I think that this can be obtained asociating the characteristic equation, but I don't know how to do this. (I saw an example in which the solution was obtained in this way.)

Comment: I have to solve this equation as a difference equation.

Comment: Then look for solution so feo the homogéneos equation of the form $r^n$ and a constant particular solution of the complete equation.

Comment: If $u_i = D$ is a constant particular solution of the complete equation, then we have $$-(1+Pe) D + 2 D - (1-Pe) D - \frac{h^2}{\epsilon} = 0$$                 $$\Leftrightarrow (-1-Pe + 2 - 1 + Pe) D - \frac{h^2}{\epsilon} = 0$$                  $$\Leftrightarrow 0 D - \frac{h^2}{\epsilon} = 0$$ but $\epsilon \neq 0, \; h \neq 0$.

Comment: To tell the truth I had not carried out the computations. I have included them in the answer.